# Complex Date extraction from Json python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

This looks outright simple  but for some weird reason i'm not getting the desired output.

1. Pass a date and retrieve only that date related information and the loc from the json
2. If the date is unavailable pick the most recent date next to the unavailable date (ex: '2020-01-05' is not there but 2020-01-04 is available, so pick 2020-01-04 only if 05 is not available )
3. If date or the most recent is not available then be it 'no date available to pick'.

```
def (date_val)
  try:
     x= json.loads(json_data.text)
     name= x['name']
     age= x['age']
     result= { "name":name, "age":age, "date";"", "location":"" }
     data.append(result)
   except Exception:
     print("error occured")
     result= {"name": "error", "age": "error", "date";"", "location":""  }
   else:
      for i in x['dates']:
          if date_val == i['date']:
                  date= i['date']
                  loc= i['location']
          else:
               #how to handle the condition after the else, and also append to the result dic
```

```
{
 "name":  "alexis",
 "age" :  "12",
  "dates":[
           { 
             "date": "2020-01-20",
             "location": "bristol"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-01-20",
             "location": "cardiff"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-01-20",
             "location": "na"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-10-14",
             "location": "liverpool"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-02-20",
             "location": "london"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-02-20",
             "location": "nashire"
           },
           { 
             "date": "2020-07-12",
             "location": "yshire"
           },           
            { 
             "date": "2020-03-10",
             "location": "loudre"
           }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line using list comprehension:

```
import json
from dateutil.parser import parse

def func(date_val):
    try:
        # x has json data
        result = { "name": name, "age":age }
        closest = min(x['dates'], key=lambda y: abs(parse(y['date']) - parse(date_val)))
        result.update(closest)
        print(result)            
    except Exception as ex:
        print("error occured", ex)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.will this code return the location as well? Because when i tried by self, it assembles the date well but the location was unseen

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can leave your other code as is. I have just added the fix for nearest date only.

Comment: if i add [location] in the lambda next to y. would that fetch the location as well? I missed to add it in the desc to have even the location get picked up along with the date.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you explain how is the location returned from here? will this code fail if we extra key value pairs after location. ( ex: {date: , location: , desc: }

Comment: `closest` is a dict with the info about closest date and location. we are just using update to result dict. the code will have no key, value pairs for date and location if the `dates` list is empty. It will add a proper date and location in all cases.

Comment: what if the dates dictionary has 3 key/values like {date: , location: , desc: } . At that case would "desc" bealso  updated to the result. or is there a way to pick only date and location from the results, ie the key/val that we only need.

Comment: `closest` will contain output of all the keys present in `x['dates']` list element. you can prune the elements you don't need by using `del` function.